# Why did the session of Apache IoTDB reported await session pool.Open(false)?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone used C# to call Apache IoTDB? When opening the session using C#, the connection failed error message `await session pool.Open(false)` is always reported, and the network cannot reach port 6667 via telnet. I checked that the firewall has already been turned off (so it should not be a problem) and there is no problem with the starting port `6667`. I can also access the server of IoTDB database using the `finalShell` tool. Anyone know what may the reason for my problem and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access Apache IoTDB from a server other than the one where IoTDB is located, then you can modify the configuration `dn_rpc_address` in `apache-iotdb-1.1.0-all-bin\conf\iotdb-datanode` path to the IP of the server where IoTDB is located, or change it to 0.0.0.0.